# How to store all hyperlinks from a scrolling web table?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I want to store some hyperlinks in a list from a web table.
website = https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products
[image: Picture of webtable]

on the above table, you can see "PRODUCT" column and hyperlinks on the column content. I want to store only those hyperlinks avoiding other hyperlinks on the page.

```
<sgx-table-list data-rendered-rows="30" data-visible-rows="15" data-rendered-index="0" data-visible-index="0" style="min-width: 860px; transform: translateY(0px);">
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="187" data-row-index="0" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(0px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZADS">Adani P &amp; S Eco Zone Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZADS=my SP Equity</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZADSsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZADS&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="188" data-row-index="1" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(32px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZACE">Ambuja Cements Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZACE=my SP Equity</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZACEsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZACE&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="189" data-row-index="2" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(64px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZAPN">Asian Paints Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZAPN=my SP Equity</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZAPNsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZAPN&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="190" data-row-index="3" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(96px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZARB">Aurobindo Pharma Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZARB=my SP Equity</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZARBsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZARB&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="191" data-row-index="4" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(128px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZAXS">Axis Bank Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZAXS=my SP Equity</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZAXSsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZAXS&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="192" data-row-index="5" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(160px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZBJA">Bajaj Auto Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZBJA=my SP Equity</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZBJAsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZBJA&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="193" data-row-index="6" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(192px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZBAF">Bajaj Finance Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZBAF=my SP Equity</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZBAFsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZBAF&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="194" data-row-index="7" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(224px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZBPC">Bharat Petroleum Corp Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZBPC=my SP Equity</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZBPCsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZBPC&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="195" data-row-index="8" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(256px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZBHA">Bharti Airtel Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZBHA=my SP Equity</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZBHAsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZBHA&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="196" data-row-index="9" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(288px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZBHI">Bharti Infratel Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZBHI=my SP Equity</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZBHIsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZBHI&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="197" data-row-index="10" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(320px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZBOS">Bosch Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZBOS=my SP Equity</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZBOSsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZBOS&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="198" data-row-index="11" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(352px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZCIP">Cipla Ltd India Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZCIP=my SP Equity</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZCIPsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZCIP&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="199" data-row-index="12" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(384px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZCOA">Coal India Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZCOA=my SP Equity</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZCOAsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZCOA&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="237" data-row-index="13" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(416px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/sgssfs?cc=YCDD">Comfortdelgro Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">YCDD=my SP EQUITY </sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#YCDDsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=YCDD&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="238" data-row-index="14" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(448px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/sgssfs?cc=YDBS">DBS Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">YDBS=my SP EQUITY </sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#YDBSsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=YDBS&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="200" data-row-index="15" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(480px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZDRR">Dr Reddy's Laboratories Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZDRR=my SP Equity</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZDRRsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZDRR&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="201" data-row-index="16" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(512px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZEIM">Eicher Motors Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZEIM=my SP Equity</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZEIMsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZEIM&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="202" data-row-index="17" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(544px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZGAI">GAIL India Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZGAI=my SP Equit</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZGAIsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZGAI&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="239" data-row-index="18" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(576px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/sgssfs?cc=YGEN">Genting Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">YGEN=my SP EQUITY </sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#YGENsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=YGEN&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="203" data-row-index="19" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(608px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZHCL">HCL Technologies Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZHCL=my SP Equity</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZHCLsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZHCL&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="204" data-row-index="20" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(640px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZHDB">HDFC Bank Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZHDB=my SP Equity</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZHDBsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZHDB&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
```

I had to cut HTML code due to word limit. But you can see it on the website(link above)

Comment: could provide more clear details? look confusing what you looking for

Comment: With the help of this xpath you will be able to retrieve all the hyper links that are present in the table. 
****************
//div[@class='table-container']/descendant::a
****************
Now it is depend on you how you are going to process it.

Comment: @muraliselenium In the snapshot above, Can you see ''PRODUCT" column? In this column, there are around 200+ contract names and their hyperlink. I want to add those all hyperlinks in a list.

Answer (score 0):

An example.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, req, utils
html = '''
<sgx-table-list data-rendered-rows="30" data-visible-rows="15" data-rendered-index="0" data-visible-index="0" style="min-width: 860px; transform: translateY(0px);">
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="187" data-row-index="0" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(0px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZADS">Adani P &amp; S Eco Zone Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZADS=my SP Equity</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZADSsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZADS&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
   <sgx-table-row data-row-id="188" data-row-index="1" style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(32px);">
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="product" data-first="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 320px; left: 0px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZACE">Ambuja Cements Futures</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="true" data-autowidth="false" data-column-id="type" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 100px; left: 320px;">Futures</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="bloomberg-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">ZACE=my SP Equity</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-text data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="reuters-code" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 160px;">0#ZACEsi:</sgx-table-cell-text>
      <sgx-table-cell-link data-frozen="false" data-autowidth="true" data-column-id="delayed-prices" data-last="true" class="sgx-table-cell" style="width: 120px;"><a target="_blank" class="website-link" href="https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZACE&amp;category=ssf">View</a></sgx-table-cell-link>
   </sgx-table-row>
</sgx-table-list>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
lst = doc.getElement('sgx-table-list',attr='style',value='min-width: 860px; transform: translateY(0px);')
lstA = lst.selects('a')
print (lstA.href)
```

Result:

```
['https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZADS', 'https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZADS&category=ssf', 'https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZACE', 'https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=ZACE&category=ssf']
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Answer (score 0):

With Selenium, either of these two should return the list of hrefs under Product:

```
#by CSS
product_links=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.table-container a[href*=products]")
```

or

```
#by XPATH
product_links=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='table-container']//a[contains(@href,'products')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get all links from the page:

```
#Store all <a>'s from Product column
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//sgx-table-cell-link[@data-column-id='product']/a")
#Get href from <a>'s
links = [elements.get_attribute('href') for link in elements]
```